# How do I block the window.on('beforeUnload') event for <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-events

In my project I need to get the user confirmation alert , when the user want to close the window/tab using **X button**.

But the `window.on('beforeUnload')` also works for **hyper link** . How can I block this `leave page` alert for `<a>` tag ?

My **JSP** will have the

```
<a href="next.jsp" id="navigate"> click here </a>
```

My **Jquery** will have ,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navigate').on('click', function() {
    stopNavigate(event);
    });
    
});

function stopNavigate(event){   
    $(window).off('beforeunload', function(){
        
    });
}


$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).on('unload', function(){
    logout();


});
```

I don't want the `leave message alert` when the user click any `links`. I need the `leave message alert` only for **window close operation**.

Comment: Are you really asking how to get confirmation when they close the window, rather than navigate away from it, because there are lots of ways they could navigate away from the current page, without using links.

Comment: `$(window).off('beforeunload');` and maybe you need to call it on mousedown (mouseup?) handler of anchor, not click handler

Comment: @Archer No .I don't want the leave message alert when the user click any links. I need it only for window closes .

Comment: So you're happy with the message showing when they click the back button?

Comment: @Wolff That works as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navigate').on('mouseenter', stopNavigate)
        .on('mouseout', function () {
        $(window).on('beforeunload', windowBeforeUnload);
    });

});

function stopNavigate(event) {
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
}

function windowBeforeUnload() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
}

$(window).on('beforeunload', windowBeforeUnload);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LtLtg/14/show)

Comment: I will give 10000 + points, If it is possible. But sorry , I can give only +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$("a").mousedown(function() {
    $(window).unbind();
});
```