# jquery capture cleave window but not refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this javascript script with jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'exit.php',
        async:false,
        data: 'param=userEXIT'
    });
});
```

This script works perfectly, however, is possible to change for capture the exit actions of the user (for closure or link to another page) and NOT when user update the page?

Comment: So, you want to detect whether or not a user is actually _leaving_, and not just loading a different page on your website?

Comment: Yes, only when user leave the page

Comment: No it is not possible to know of what action caused the page to exit and you are causing the page to hang.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're out of luck. JavaScript can not distinguish between those 2 cases.

Comment: i'm quite sure your onunload handler doesn't work in a cross browser way. Have you tested it on chrome e.g? Anyway, you could unbind onunload event when user click on any anchor tag

Comment: I tested only with firefox, but a way to capture the individual action it's an idea.
I was hoping there was an easier way :)

Comment: see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/a/18824483/1414562 But be aware AFAIK, there is no cross browser way of doing what you are trying to do, send an ajax request (and sure it completes) when user leave page