# Why doesn't an F5 key press in Chrome remove AJAX-added elements from the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm loading more elements on to the page via AJAX. The elements are loaded when the user scrolls to the bottom of the browser window. I've noticed that if I am viewing the very top of the page and I hit F5, the elements I have loaded via my script are removed from the page. However, if I'm scrolled half-way down the page and I hit F5, the elements that have been loaded via my script **aren't** removed - they remain on the page. I would have expected the AJAX-added elements would be removed on F5 press regardless of where I have scrolled to in the browser window.

**UPDATE:** This happens in Chrome only.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: When you hit F5 does your browser take you back to the top of the page, or does it send you to the same place you were prior to hitting F5?

Comment: Same behaviour on all major browsers?! Could you provide online link?

Comment: It doesn't send me to the top of the page. Instead it sends me to roughly the same place where I was scrolled to before I hit F5.

Comment: @A.Wolff So far I've tested in Chrome only. It isn't live yet, I was hoping to go live once I figure out what is happening with this

Comment: could this be a caching issue?

Comment: I just tried using `$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false });` to disable caching of the response and it resolved the problem. The AJAX-added elements must have been cached. `F5` or `Ctrl + F5` didn't seem to clear that so were useless in this case.

Comment: Actually that hasn't resolved the issue. On occasion, I still don't get all added-elements removed on F5 or Ctrl + F5

Comment: @A.Wolff I just tried in both FireFox and Safari and it seems this problem only happens in Chrome.

Comment: @henrywright Well i guess because of keeping scrolled position, ajax request are resend on chrome, reloading relevant content. Maybe you could try: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
});` but this won't be specific to only refreshing page

Comment: @A.Wolff Genius! that seems to have nailed it. if a user hits F5 then i'd assume they'd want a complete refresh (i.e. start again) so going back to the top of the page (losing the scrolled position) is a completely reasonable approach AND it resolves the issue!

Comment: @henrywright issue could be if user use browser's back button or backspace key, old page will be scrolled to top which user wouldn't expecting it. Solution could be then to use: `$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    if (this.refreshing) this.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 116) { // User presses F5 to refresh
        this.refreshing = true;
    }
});` But then if user refreshes page using browser button, old issue appears again...

Comment: @A.Wolff i see. I noticed also that if there are links on the page and a user clicks one, before they're taken to the link destination the current page scrolls to the top - which might be slightly confusing to the user as they'd wonder why scrolling to the top was necessary before changing to the new page

Comment: @henrywright You can avoid easily clicking on anchor tags to srcoll to top, unbinding onbeforeunload event, e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18824483/1414562 . The issue is more about user clicking browser's refresh button which i'm out of idea to find any workaround.

Comment: @A.Wolff do you mean like this? `$('a').mousedown(function() { $(window).unbind(); });`

Regarding clicking a browser's refresh button - thanks for highlighting that issue - i'll try looking into a workaround. Appreciate all your help today! thanks again

Comment: Thought i'd mention `$(document).scrollTop(0);` ensures the initial problem is resolved with no side-effects aside from the back-button issue highlighted by @A.Wolff above