# How to check I am leaving to another website using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to show alert when user is leaving our website within same tab of the browser. I searched and found `unload` event, which triggers each time both when user is leaving or clicking our website link.

For example I'm at abc.com I must not got alert box when I'm clicking my site links. But I must got alert box when I'm writing xyz.com in address bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7080331/4543256

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` event fires when leaving the current page, however what you require (that you can detect if the user is leaving your site through it) is not possible, as it will fire for every page regardless of destination.

Comment: I have gone through this post... it is not telling whether i am leaving to different domain

Comment: You can check if user clicked anchor redirecting to other domain but you cannot check if he navigates using e.g address bar to navigate to other domain

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821011/how-do-you-prevent-javascript-page-from-navigating-away

Comment: @AliMehdi what about this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/147765/4543256

Comment: @JohnR That's not a dupe. Question here is different

Comment: Please find my edit question i elaborated more

Comment: @AliMehdi Part of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824154/how-do-i-block-the-window-onbeforeunload-event-for-a-tag/18824483#18824483  Now still unclear what you mean here: `But i must got alert box when i am writting xyz.com in alert box`, writing in alert box???

Comment: I have to agree with @A.Wolff, the question is very unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript before leaving the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080269/javascript-before-leaving-the-page)

Comment: No no... i edited... writing in address bar

Comment: So that's a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18824154/how-do-i-block-the-window-onbeforeunload-event-for-a-tag/18824483#18824483 ???

Comment: No it is not dupe of what i am asking right now

Comment: @AliMehdi So exactly how is it different? Not checking for same domain or what?

Comment: This questions tells about working with anchors... but what about If I manually reloads the same website.. Your indicated question just gives a part of solution... What about form submission and other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your question now, answer is NO, you can not do it, you can do whatever on your page in your domain, you have full control of it, but you can't not detect you are going to a different domain, just not possible, that the browser's behavior, and if the other site does not have your script, you have lost control on the browser.

For example, any time if the browser loads your script, you have all control, once it went to a different site, browser unload your script, what you can do? But sure, if you have scripts loaded, you can always check what is your current path/domain.

Comment: This is what the OP says he's doing. His issue is that it fires for every page, not just when leaving his site.

Comment: Your snippet for `change domain` is for handling iframe

Comment: `return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';` to which the correct response is, **yes and I'll never be back to this site again**

Comment: do you guys agree, there is no robust solution for OP's requirement?

Comment: @KevinSimple Yes, if i undrestand exactly all OP's requirements, there is no solution

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes, mate, just not possible, maybe future, i can see the future software UI shall be all done with JavaScript. lol

Comment: thank you for your answer... Is there any other way around?

Comment: @AliMehdi, sorry mate, in your case, unless xyz.com also loads your script, there is no way to achieve it.

Comment: @JaromandaX Shouldn't that be "Are you sure you want to have already left?" ? :)

Comment: @freedomn-m that almost sounds like a time traveller tense problem!!

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use the unload event. The thing missing is navigating away when a user clicks on your own links.

This can be achieved by adding a click handler on all your links which sets a global flag (e.g. `userClicked=true`) which can be used in the unload handler

Example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sn27jd1d/1/)):

```
var userClicked = false;
$( "body" ).delegate( "a", "click", function() {
    userClicked = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (!userClicked) {
        return "Your message";
    }
}
```